# Replace a litteral by a variable in take_while

Tags: ruby

In the following code:

```
enu = [10, 12, 11, 15]
enu.take_while {|obj| obj<=13}
```

How can I replace 13 by a variable?

```
n = 13
enu.take_while {|obj| obj<={n}} # of course does not work.
```

Comment: What's the purpose of writing the braces around the variable? With braces, you create a Hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simpler than you think:

```
enu.take_while {|obj| obj<=n}
```